# Eigenvalues of $aI + bJ$

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Just as context, this problem arose when I was looking at the adjacency matrices of moore graphs of diameter 2.

Given that $I$ is the identity matrix and $J$ is the all 1 matrix. I have constructed some matrix $aI + bJ$. I am completely stuck in terms of how to find the eigenvalues of this matrix. I have considered trying to find the characteristic polynomial, but I have no idea how I would find the determinant of such a matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $A = aI+ bJ$. Note that $A-aI = bJ$ has rank 1, so the eigenvalue $a$ has geometric multiplicity $n-1$.

So all that’s left to do is find the other eigenvalue. Trying $\lambda=a+nb$ gives that $A-\lambda I$ has diagonal entries $(1-n)b$ and all other entries $b$. In particular, the sum of all the rows is the zero vector, so this matrix is singular.

Edit: I should note it is assumed here that $b\ne 0$. If $b=0$, then $A-aI=bJ$ is the zero matrix, which has rank 0, so $A$ has eigenvalue $a$ with multiplicity $n$.

Comment: To find the other value, we can also use the trace $(a+b)n$, which is the sum of all $n$ eigenvalues with multiplicity.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Very nice! That is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

here is a matrix that shows a basis of the eigenvectors as columns, these being perpendicular to each other as well. Below is the 10 by 10 case. In smaller dimension, take the upper left square corner.

$$    
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr}
  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  2  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  3  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  4  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  5  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  6  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  7  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  8  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  9   
\end{array}
  \right).
  $$

Comment: this matrix, but its transpose with each (row) divided by its length (also they negate most rows)  to make an orthogonal matrix, is on page 97 of https://books.google.com/books?id=Wkq3BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA97&lpg=PA97&dq=Basics+of+Modern+Mathematical+Statistics+Hardle+4.24&source=bl&ots=x3Tc2uvAfT&sig=n-a3yG4uNjswd9cmDYm50cDPbRE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinvqGI64TNAhVC82MKHUSoC2QQ6AEIMTAD#v=onepage&q=Basics%20of%20Modern%20Mathematical%20Statistics%20Hardle%204.24&f=false